# Create SVG dynamically from from request data

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I've tried googling, but information on svg in html is very confusing. I have a quite complex, or at least for me, scenario:

Using jQuery I wan't to create an svg object dynamically inside a div (`id="manual-regridding-image"`) based on response data from a GET-request. The svg will contain both image-data and other svg-elements. If the GET-request fails then the entire contents of the div should be set to the message within the fail-function. Finally decision about showing the contents to the user needs to be made after the image as been fully downloaded/loaded.

What I've gotten so far is:

```
function load_grid_svg() {

    show_gridimage = true;
    $.get(
        "/api/results/gridding/svg",
        function (data) {
            svg = document.importNode(data, true);
            $("#manual-regridding-image").html(svg);
        }
    ).fail(function() {
        $("#manual-regridding-image").html("<em>Could not find the grid image! Maybe gridding failed last time?</em>");
    }).always(function() {
        if (show_gridimage) {
            $("#manual-regridding-image").show();
        } else {
            $("#manual-regridding-image").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

But the importing of the data doesn't work. It feels like this question should have been asked before, but I can't find anything applicably.

## Edit

This produces a `NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported` on the `importNode` line if I understand the traceback correctly.

## Edit 2

As indicated by @Tomalak in the comments, the response is an `XMLDocument` and to get it to correctly display the callback in the `$.get` should be:

```
    function (data) {
        $("#manual-regridding-image").append(data.documentElement);
    }
```

Comment: How does it not work? What does happen?

Comment: This is probably overkill, you could try using the [jQuery SVG plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html)

Comment: @JosephYoung I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: What's the type of `data`? Is it a document? If yes, try `document.importNode(data.documentElement)`. Also, use `.append()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: Don't think the data you get from the ajax call will be a svg document, but just the text. Either way, importNode is not needed here, you should just be able to add the svg text, if it's namespaced correctly and such.

Comment: @Shilly Depends on the `Content-Type` of the response. It's possible that `data` is an XML document here.

Comment: True. Personally I just use responseText to get the txt file representation of the .svg file. Inside the svg page, I added some hooks for the templating framework I use. After replacing the variable parts in the template, I can just append as with any other innerHTML, providing the .svg file had a correct namespace.

Comment: @deinonychusaur, Did you check the answers?

Comment: @Dekel trying my way through the answers and comments but none seems to do the trick unfortunately.

Comment: Can you provide a link or example? Are you sure your request returns the correct content? (string with svg markup `<svg>...</svg>` )

Comment: @Dekel as in my Edit 2, Tomalak correctly identified the problem, that the data was a full document and not just an string.

Comment: @Tomalak if you wish to post your comment as answer, I would accept it as your solution solved the problem.

Comment: Well, as said in my comment, if the data is correct - my solution  would work :) A vote on my answer will be appreciated though ;)

Comment: @deinonychusaur Instead of posting and edit you could also post your own answer – after all, you have found out on your own. My comment just gave you the right idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by @Tomalak in the comments, the response is an `XMLDocument` and not only the `<svg>...</svg>` string, so to get it to correctly display the callback in the `$.get` should be:

```
function (data) {
    $("#manual-regridding-image").append(data.documentElement);
}
```

To ensure the div only shows the most recent content a `$(#manual-regridding-image").empty()` needs to be performed before the `$.get`-call.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need the `document.importNode` at all.
You can just use `$.html()` to add the content of your svg to the document.

Check this example:

```js
svgstr = '<svg height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg>'

$('#btn1').click(function() {
  $('#a1').append(svgstr)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1">
  <span>Some Text</span><br />
</div>
<button id="btn1">Click to add SVG</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript You can use XMLHttpRequest and load an svg file responseText directly into the Div innerHTML. The callback function also can call any after load events. This also provides access to each svg element within the div.

See example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Load SVG into DIV</title>
</head>
<body onLoad=callSVGfile()>
<div id=mySVGdiv></div>
<script>
function callSVGfile()
{
    /*
    var SVGFile="mySVGfile.svg"
    var loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest;
    loadXML.onload = callback;
    loadXML.open("GET", SVGFile, true);
    loadXML.send();
    function callback()
    {
    //---responseText---
    mySVGdiv.innerHTML=loadXML.responseText
    }
    */
    mySVGdiv.innerHTML=loadXMLreponseText

}

var loadXMLreponseText='<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Rose1"  width="149.395" height="175.624">'+
'<polygon id="BorderPoly" fill="none" pointer-events="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="4" points="74.6978,0 46.1667,9.271 28.5328,33.542 28.5328,63.542 0.000946045,72.811 5.34058e-005,102.811 28.5328,112.083 46.1657,136.353 46.1657,166.353 74.6978,175.624 103.229,166.353 103.231,136.353 120.864,112.082 149.395,102.812 149.395,72.812 120.863,63.542 120.863,33.542 103.23,9.2705" />'+
'<g id="mainPolyG" transform=""><polygon id="mainPoly" fill="rgb(30, 144, 255)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" points="120.863,63.542 120.863,33.542 103.23,9.2705 74.6978,0 46.1667,9.271 28.5328,33.542 28.5328,63.542 46.1657,87.812 74.6978,97.083 103.23,87.812" seed="0" /><polygon fill="rgb(255, 255, 0)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" points="28.5328,112.083 46.1657,87.812 74.6978,97.083 74.6978,127.083 46.1657,136.353" seed="1" /><polygon fill="rgb(255, 255, 0)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" points="74.6987,127.083 74.6978,97.083 103.23,87.812 120.864,112.082 103.231,136.353" seed="2" /><polygon fill="rgb(255, 255, 0)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" points="120.863,112.083 103.23,87.812 120.863,63.542 149.395,72.812 149.395,102.812" seed="3" /><polygon fill="rgb(255, 255, 0)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" points="0.000946045,72.811 28.5328,63.542 46.1657,87.812 28.5317,112.083 5.34058e-005,102.811" seed="4" /><polygon fill="rgb(237, 28, 36)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" points="74.6978,127.083 46.1657,136.353 74.6978,145.624 103.229,136.353" seed="5" /><polygon fill="rgb(0, 255, 0)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" points="74.6978,145.624 103.229,136.353 103.229,166.353 74.6978,175.624" seed="6" /><polygon fill="rgb(0, 255, 0)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" points="46.1657,166.353 46.1657,136.353 74.6978,145.624 74.6978,175.624" seed="7" /></g>'+
'</svg>'
</script>
</body>

</html>
```